# Error: the template "phonegap-template-push" was not found

Tags: macos, cordova, push-notification

I have Cordova 5.0.0, and PhoneGap CLI 5.0.0-0.27.1, and I'm on a Mac OS X 10.10.5. I've been attempting to follow the directions of http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/push-notifications/ but every time I put in the first command `phonegap create CLIMobile --template phonegap-template-push` it kicks back to me with the error: `[error] the template "phonegap-template-push" was not found`

I've repeated the same steps at my home computer which is windows 10, and it worked fine.

Help?

Comment: Hm. Sure looks like the cordova community is fairly dead on StackOverflow. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your recent unanswered question because I was searching for a solution to this exact error.  Apparently we are the only two people to encounter it.  I just figured out a solution, so here it is.

First, you need to open up the package.json file in your phonegap installation, which is probably at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/.  Once you've opened that up (for editing), scroll down until you see the templates section.

This is where PhoneGap is referencing it's template list.  Notice the template you are trying to use isn't listed.  You'll need to add it and point to where PhoneGap can find it.

Below is an example of what that section should look like after you've done that.

```
  "templates": {
    "blank": {
      "description": "A blank and empty PhoneGap app.",
      "url": "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-blank/archive/master.tar.gz"
    },
    "hello-world": {
      "description": "Default hello world app for PhoneGap.",
      "url": "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/master.tar.gz"
    },
    "hello-cordova": {
      "description": "Default hello world app for Cordova.",
      "url": "https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world/archive/master.tar.gz"
    },
    "jquery-mobile-starter": {
      "description": "Starter PhoneGap project using jQuery Mobile.",
      "url": "https://github.com/cfjedimaster/jQuery-Mobile-Starter/archive/master.tar.gz"
    },
    "phonegap-template-push": {
      "description": "phonegap-template-push",
      "url": "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-push/archive/master.tar.gz"
    }
  },
```

Save and close that, then retry the command:

```
phonegap create myApp --template phonegap-template-push
```

Hopefully you will see this output:

```
Downloading phonegap-template-push-template library for www...
Download complete
```

Comment: You are brilliant and awesome. Thank you!